# How to supply fftw path to g++ for installation of FIt-SNE

Tags: installation, g++, fftw

I guess I don't have enough experience installing software with g++. I am trying to install [FIt-SNE](https://github.com/KlugerLab/FIt-SNE). I am following the installation instructions. I have already installed FFTW, and I just need to execute the following line:

```
g++ -std=c++11 -O3  src/sptree.cpp src/tsne.cpp src/nbodyfft.cpp  -o bin/fast_tsne -pthread -lfftw3 -lm -Wno-address-of-packed-member
```

And I get this error:

```
In file included from src/tsne.cpp:40:0:
src/nbodyfft.h:7:10: fatal error: fftw3.h: No such file or directory
 #include <fftw3.h>
          ^~~~~~~~~
compilation terminated.
In file included from src/nbodyfft.cpp:5:0:
src/nbodyfft.h:7:10: fatal error: fftw3.h: No such file or directory
 #include <fftw3.h>
          ^~~~~~~~~
compilation terminated.
```

I understand that the installer is not finding the FFTW package, and I think I need to provide the path to the installation somehow to the installer, but I don't know how to do it. Can anyone help me with this?

Comment: You are on linux? Could you please post the result of `cat /etc/os-release` into your question?

Comment: I am having this problem as well.